# Controlling view position of initialScrollIndex of FlatList

Tags: react-native

I want to start the offset of my list but move the initial viewPosition. The FlatList is currently showing the current image + next image on the list but rather would want to show the current image + previous one.

I'm already using initialScrollIndex and I can scrollToIndex of the image but I'm thinking that it might show some jank on first mount

Here is the image with initialScrollIndex exactly on the item I want. 
[image: screenshot]

The behavior I want is using initialScrollIndex and showing the previous item instead of the next.
[image: screenshot]

```
export default class App extends Component {
    flatList = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {

            this.flatList.scrollToIndex({
                index: 3,
                animated: false,
                viewPosition: 1
            })
        }, 10)
    }

    setFlatList = (ref) => {
        this.flatList = ref;
    }

    getItemLayout = (_, index) => ({
        index,
        length: 600,
        offset: 600 * index
    });

    renderItem = ({ index }) => {
        const backgroundColor =
            index === 0 ? "blue" : index === 1 ? "red" : index === 2 ? "green" : index === 3 ? "yellow" : "white";
        return (
            <View style={{ height: 600, backgroundColor, width: 450, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text>{`item${index}`}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}>
                    <FlatList keyExtractor={(_, index) => `${index}`} getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout} ref={this.setFlatList} data={["yo", "1", "2", "3", "4"]} renderItem={this.renderItem} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: please provide code with it….